# How to access name from Chakra-ui NumberInput component?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'd like to dynamically update my local state with one handler. In a regular input I would expect an event.target property with name and value.

Number input does not appear to return the event. How do I access the name of the component in my change handler??

component state

```
const [advanceOptions, setAdvanceOptions] = useState({
   swapFee: 1,
   lpFee: 0,
})
```

component onchange handler

```
const onAdvanceOptionChange = (_, val) => {
  // I'd like to be able to use the statement below but NumberInput
  // does not appear to pass the event.
  setAdvanceOptions(prevState => ({...prevState, [name]: val})
}
```

component JSX

```
<>
<InputGroup>
  <NumberInput
   name="swapFee"
   value={advanceOptions.swapFee}
   onChange={(_, value) => onAdvanceOptionChange(value)}
   >
     <NumberInputField/>
   </NumberInput>
</InputGroup>
<InputGroup>
  <NumberInput
   name="lpFee"
   value={advanceOptions.lpFee}
   onChange={(_, value) => onAdvanceOptionChange(value)}
   >
     <NumberInputField/>
   </NumberInput>
</InputGroup>
</>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/617

You're right, number input does not return the event, although you can use Formik to achieve what you want to achieve.

Here is my little hack

```js
const formChange = (event) => {
  setFormValues((prev) => ({
    ...prev,
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  }))
}

...

<NumberInput
  name={'salary'}
  value={formValues.salary}
  onChange={(value) => formChange({ target: { name: 'salary', value }})}
>
  <NumberInputField />
  <NumberInputStepper>
    <NumberIncrementStepper />
    <NumberDecrementStepper />
  </NumberInputStepper>
</NumberInput>
```